# FBX export: object pivot is set to center of the scene

Tags: objects, .fbx, unreal-engine

Whenever I export my mesh to FBX format (for use inside UE4) its pivot is set to center of the Blender scene (0,0,0), not respecting the original object's pivot position.

Does anyone know why or how to solve this, so that once imported into UE4 object's pivot would be where it should be instead being way off because it is set to original Blender scene center?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I found the correct answer myself: if you use **File -> Import Into Level** instead of the expected normal Import function, then the import process is a bit different.

It will automatically create Blueprint for you with the root pivot still at the bottom center at 0,0,0 but **now every object in there will have its own original pivot** as seen in Blender...and that's it!